# Regular expression with decimal and character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will accept the following:

```
s#.#
f#.#
```

Where # can be an integer of any size (so really, a decimal preceded by s or f).  I also need this to accept nothing else.  So if it's something like:

```
As#.# would not be accepted because there's an A before the s
s#.#X would not be accepted because there's an X after the decimal.
```

There will always be either an s or an f to start, then a number, a period, and another number.  All those parts are required and the numbers can be any size and any number of integers.

Comment: What does "accept nothing else" mean exactly?

Comment: Given the question could have more than a dozen answers, it isin't clear at all. Maybe you could give more examples.

Comment: It appears the question was truncated, I had examples of what I meant, I'll add them back, but the answer posted seems to have figured out what I meant anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^[sf]\d+\.\d+$/
```

**Explanation**

- `^` is an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) that matches the start of the string.
- `[sf]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and means an `s` or an `f`.
- `\d` means a digit.
- `+` means one or more.
- `\.` matches a literal dot.
- `$` is an anchor that matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Requiring the decimal:

```
/^[sf]\d+\.\d+$/
```

Not requiring the decimal:

```
/^[sf]\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Not allowing leading zeroes:

```
/^[sf][1-9]\d*\.\d+$/
```

Not requiring the decimal, not allowing leading zeroes:

```
/^[sf][1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/
```

These are fairly trivial regexes, but I hope it inspires you to learn more as you go.  They are immensely useful.